# Without updating the column values in Oracle , is there a way to store the data in a variable and get a count on those data using where condition?

Tags: database, oracle, variables, plsql, temp

I am new to Oracle. I need some help in this. So the scenario is that without updating any column value in the table I have to store a DATE value and from that DATE value I have to get a count based on a where condition, which i know we will use a '<=' operator.

For Example,lets say i have a column "Sweep_Date", in this column,for the time being all the values are **nulll**.

I am having nearly 2,92,300 rows in which I have to update the date values. But without updating the **Sweep_Date** column, Is there any way that i can store some dates in the column, for which i can write a where condition and get the count(*) from the table based upon the WHERE condition applied??

Can we use a temp Variable??

Any help is appreciated......

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. SWEEP_DATE is empty. You want to update that column. But, before updating it, you want to use it in a WHERE clause as if it was populated. That just doesn't make sense to me. Please, illustrate what you are saying with some sample data.

Comment: See, "SWEEP_DATE" is empty or having nulls. I dont have to update SWEEP_DATE column coz it is production data. So without updating I have to write a query or Procedure where i can get all the data as if i have updated it.                                             Can we do this using a temp variable in the PROC/QUERY(anything is ok).                     If we update it, we will get some date values in it, but without getting updated where we can store that data.

Comment: For Example:""SWEEP_DATE"" is null and if we update it(i dont want to update), i will get it as "27-MAY-2017". Like this we need to virtually update for 292K rows and after that as i said earlier i will add a where condition saying that "Select count(*) from table where SWEEP_DATE <= 31-DEC-2021".                                                                                 Can we achieve this without updating the Prod data ??

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I think I got it.

If `sweep_date` is empty and you can't/won't update it, then use `NVL` function. For example:

```
select count(*)
from your_table t
where nvl(t.sweep_date, date '2020-04-28') > t.some_other_date;
```

---

If you use date column from another table, then join tables and use another table's column in `NVL`. For example:

```
select count(*)
from your_table t join another_table j on j.some_id = t.some_id
where nvl(t.sweep_date, j.some_date) > t.some_other_date;
```

Comment: And one more problem is,,,, this date '2020-04-28' should come from another table...Then wat to do??

Comment: You'd join tables and use another table's column in NVL. I edited my answer; have a look.